# Uncaught ReferenceError: messageChecking is not defined

Tags: php, javascript, ajax

Добрый день и сразу извинюсь, если вдруг продублировал вопрос, однако ответа совсем не нашел. Сразу суть проблемы:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#create1').click(function() {
        $.ajax({
            url:"create.php",
            cache:false,
            success:function(html) {
                $("#mainContent").html(html);
            }
        });
    });
    $('#create2').click(function() {
        $.ajax({
            url:"create2.php",
            cache:false,
            success:function(html) {
                $("#mainContent").html(html);
            }
        });
    });
    $('#tasks').click(function() {
        $.ajax({
            url:"tasks.php",
            cache:false,
            success:function(html) {
                $("#mainContent").html(html);
            }
        });
    });
    $('#msg').click(function() {
        $.ajax({
            url:"msg.php",
            cache:false,
            success:function(html) {
                $("#mainContent").html(html);
            }
        });
    });
    function messageChecking () {
        $.ajax({
            url:'/msgcheck.php',
            type:'POST',
            success:function(response) {
                alert('Script is running!');
                result = jQuery.parseJSON(response);
                if (result.countmsg != <?php echo $cc; ?>)
                {
                    document.getElementById("countmsg").innerHTML = "Cообщения (" + result.countmsg + ")";
                    var audio = new Audio();
                    audio.src = 'notify.mp3';
                    audio.autoplay = true;
                }
                Timer()
            }
        })
    }
    function Timer () {
        setTimeout('messageChecking()', 1000);
    }
    Timer();
});
</script>
```

проблема:
Uncaught ReferenceError: messageChecking is not defined
    at anonymous:1:1

Все остальное, кроме функции таймера, которую вычитал здесь работает, но эту функцию своими руками вставить не смог. Как разобраться?

Comment: зачем зацикливать `setTimeout` если можно сделать `setInterval` ?

Comment: С обычным setInterval все заработало, спасибо

Answer (score 1):

Замените

```
setTimeout('messageChecking()', 1000);
```

на

```
setTimeout(function() {
    messageChecking();
}, 1000);
```

Если передавать имя функции строкой - то интерпретатор js будет искать эту функцию в глобальной области видимости, вот пример:

```
function bar(a) {
    alert("глобально "+a)
}
function foo() {
    function bar(a) {
        alert("внутри foo "+a)
    }
    function timer1() {
        setTimeout(function() {
            bar('вызвано из timer1')
        }, 1000)
    }
     function timer2() {
        setTimeout("bar('вызвано из timer2')", 1000)
    }
    timer1()
    timer2()
}

foo()
```

Смотрите, при вызове setTimeout("bar('вызвано из timer2')" - внутренняя функция bar не находится, находится только глобальная, однако при вызове из функции - внутренняя bar будет найдена.

Потеря контекста происходит из за того, что при использовании строки с вызовом ф-и у нас создается новый объект Function и в его конструктор передается эта строка. Scope этого объекта по умолчанию - window, соответственно внутренняя ф-я не видна.

Почему не стоит использовать

```
setTimeout(messageChecking, 1000);
```

Если вы захотите передать аргументы внутрь функции вам придется указать их как аргументы для setTimeout:

```
setTimeout(messageChecking, 1000, arg1, arg2);
```

Для того что бы обработать такой код javascript внутри себя будет использовать медленную ф-ю apply, как итог - потеря производительности.

Comment: зачем функцию запаковывать еще в одну функцию? разве просто `setTimeout(messageChecking,1000)` не будет работать?

Comment: Написал дополнение к ответу, можете причитать и посмотреть код.

Материалы по теме: https://learn.javascript.ru/settimeout-setinterval#settimeout

https://learn.javascript.ru/scope-new-function

Comment: Но в данном кейсе получается, что `setTimeout(messageChecking, 1000);` подходит.

Comment: да, в данном кейсе это применимо

Answer (score 0):

> ```
> setTimeout('messageChecking()', 1000);
> ```

```
setTimeout(messageChecking, 1000);
```